# Why do my canvas shapes not appear the first time they are drawn?

Tags: python, canvas, kivy

So I'm making a simple maths game, but the shapes I create with a canvas that is assigned to a button widget don't show up when a function is called, but only after you refresh them by clicking another button that runs the exact same function.

Here is the .kv code of one of the title screen buttons:

```
TitleScreenButton:
    id:titlescreenbutton6
    text: "Simple"
    pos_hint: {"x":0.33333, "y":0.66666}
    on_release: root.gensimple()
```

The function the button calls simply sets the values of a bunch of integers, then finishing with the line self.showbuttons():

```
def showbuttons(self):
    for id, object in self.ids.items():
        object.opacity = 0
        object.size_hint =0,0
    self.storeresultcurrentvalue = 0
    self.storedresult = False
    for id, object in self.ids.items():
        if id.startswith("calcbutton"):
            y = int(id.replace("calcbutton", "")) - 1
            if self.calcenabled[y] == 1:
                object.size_hint = 0.18, 0.18
                object.opacity = 100
                object.disabled = False
                object.color = 1,1,1,0
                object.background_color = 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0
                object.background_normal = ''
                object.canvas.clear()
                object.canvas.before.clear()
                object.canvas.after.clear()
                self.buttonpress(object, object.state)
```

And self.buttonpress(object,object.state) does the following:

```
    def buttonpress(self,instance,state):
    if state == "down":
        instance.pos = (instance.x, instance.y - instance.height * 0.1)
    self.setcolors(instance)
    instance.canvas.clear()
    instance.canvas.before.clear()
    instance.canvas.after.clear()
    with instance.canvas.before:
        Color(self.buttonr * 0.7, self.buttong * 0.7, self.buttonb * 0.7, 1)
        if state=="down":
            RoundedRectangle(pos=(instance.x, instance.y - instance.height * 0.01), size=instance.size,radius=[10, 10, 10, 10])
        else:
            RoundedRectangle(pos=(instance.x,instance.y-instance.height*0.1),size=instance.size,radius= [10,10,10,10])
        Color(self.buttonr,self.buttong,self.buttonb,1)
        RoundedRectangle(pos=(instance.x, instance.y), size=instance.size,radius=[10, 10, 10, 10])
        Color(0.2,0.2,0.2,1)
        RoundedRectangle(pos=(instance.x+instance.width*0.025, instance.y+ instance.height * 0.05), size=(instance.width*0.95,instance.height*0.9),radius=[10, 10, 10, 10])
        Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
    my_label = CoreLabel(text=str(instance.text),text_size=(instance.width,instance.height),font_size=instance.height,colorfmt='rgba',color=(1, 1, 1, 1),halign= 'center')
    my_label.refresh()
    hello_texture = my_label.texture
    instance.canvas.add(Rectangle(texture=hello_texture,size= (instance.width*0.7,instance.height*0.7), pos=(instance.x+(instance.width*0.5)-(my_label.width*0.35), instance.y+instance.height*0.1),colorfmt='rgba',color=(0, 0, 1, 1)))
```

So after this code you see the following:

[Game screen after you click one of the buttons on the title screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z824.png)

And the buttons are invisible, but if you click the retry button, the code of which is:

```
Button:
    id:calcretry
    text: "RETRY"
    size_hint: 0.2,0.1
    pos_hint: {"x":0.45, "y":0.7}
    on_release:
        root.showbuttons()
```

[Game screen after you click the retry button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuMNc.png)

The buttons just decide to show up for no reason? Is there a way to update the canvas? I can provide further clarification if need be.

Here is the main.py and .kv code for the minimum reproductible example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from random import randint
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.graphics import Color, RoundedRectangle
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
Window.size = (500, 400)
Window.minimum_width, Window.minimum_height = Window.size
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)

class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):

    def get_id(self, instance):
        for id, object in instance.parent.ids.items():
            if object.__self__ == instance:
                return id

    def gensettings(self):
        self.calcenabled = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.enabledbuttons = []
        self.enabledbuttons.clear()
        a = randint(self.enabledbuttonsmin, self.enabledbuttonsmax)
        b = 0
        for i in range(9):
            self.calcenabled[i] = 0
            if b < a:
                self.calcenabled[i] = randint(0, 1)
                if self.calcenabled[i] == 1:
                    b = b + 1
                    self.enabledbuttons.append(i)

        self.showbuttons()

    def gensimple(self):
        self.enabledbuttonsmax = 4
        self.enabledbuttonsmin = 2
        self.gensettings()
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------show main buttons
    def showbuttons(self):
        for id, object in self.ids.items():
            object.opacity = 0
            object.size_hint =0,0
        for id, object in self.ids.items():
            if id.startswith("calc"):
                object.opacity = 100
                object.disabled = False
            if id.startswith("titlescreenbutton"):
                object.disabled = False
                object.opacity = 100
                object.size_hint = 0.1, 0.1
                object.pos_hint = {"x":0}
        for id, object in self.ids.items():
            if id.startswith("calcbutton"):
                y = int(id.replace("calcbutton", "")) - 1
                if self.calcenabled[y] == 1:
                    object.size_hint = 0.18, 0.18
                    object.opacity = 100
                    object.disabled = False
                    object.color = 1,1,1,0
                    object.background_color = 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0
                    self.buttonpress(object, object.state)
                if self.calcenabled[int(id.replace("calcbutton", ""))-1] == 0:
                    object.opacity = 0
                    object.disabled = True
                    object.size_hint = 0, 0
            if id.startswith("calcretry"):
                object.opacity = 100
                object.size_hint = 0.2,0.15
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def buttonpress(self,instance,state):
        if state == "down":
            instance.pos = (instance.x, instance.y - instance.height * 0.1)
        instance.canvas.clear()
        instance.canvas.before.clear()
        instance.canvas.after.clear()
        with instance.canvas.before:
            Color(0.7, 0, 0, 1)
            if state=="down":
                RoundedRectangle(pos=(instance.x, instance.y - instance.height * 0.01), size=instance.size,radius=[10, 10, 10, 10])
            else:
                RoundedRectangle(pos=(instance.x,instance.y-instance.height*0.1),size=instance.size,radius= [10,10,10,10])
            Color(1,0,0,1)
            RoundedRectangle(pos=(instance.x, instance.y), size=instance.size,radius=[10, 10, 10, 10])
            Color(0.2,0.2,0.2,1)
            RoundedRectangle(pos=(instance.x+instance.width*0.025, instance.y+ instance.height * 0.05), size=(instance.width*0.95,instance.height*0.9),radius=[10, 10, 10, 10])
            Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
        my_label = CoreLabel(text=str(instance.text),text_size=(instance.width,instance.height),font_size=instance.height,colorfmt='rgba',color=(1, 1, 1, 1),halign= 'center')
        my_label.refresh()
        hello_texture = my_label.texture
        instance.canvas.add(Rectangle(texture=hello_texture,size= (instance.width*0.7,instance.height*0.7), pos=(instance.x+(instance.width*0.5)-(my_label.width*0.35), instance.y+instance.height*0.1),colorfmt='rgba',color=(0, 0, 1, 1)))


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyFloatLayout()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()

''' KV FILE
<Button>
    font_size: self.height*0.6
    color: 1,1,1,1
    background_color: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
    size_hint: 0,0
    disabled: True
    opacity: 0
<TitleScreenButton@Button>
    font_size: self.height*0.6
    color: 1,1,1,1
    background_color: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
    size_hint: 0.33333,0.11111
    disabled: False
    opacity: 100


<MyFloatLayout>:
    Button:
        id:calcbutton1
        background_normal: 'back0.png'
        text: "1"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "y":0.48}
        on_state: root.buttonpress(self,self.state)
        

    Button:
        id:calcbutton2
        text: "2"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.41, "y":0.48}
        on_state: root.buttonpress(self,self.state)
        

    Button:
        id:calcbutton3
        text: "3"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.62, "y":0.48}
        on_state: root.buttonpress(self,self.state)
        
    Button:
        id:calcbutton4
        text: "4"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "y":0.26}
        on_state: root.buttonpress(self,self.state)

        
    Button:
        id:calcbutton5
        text: "5"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.41, "y":0.26}
        on_state: root.buttonpress(self,self.state)
        
    Button:
        id:calcbutton6
        text: "6"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.62, "y":0.26}
        on_state: root.buttonpress(self,self.state)
        
    Button:
        text: "7"
        id:calcbutton7
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "y":0.04}
        on_state: root.buttonpress(self,self.state)
        
    Button:
        id:calcbutton8
        text: "8"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.41, "y":0.04}
        on_state: root.buttonpress(self,self.state)
        
    Button:
        id:calcbutton9
        text: "9"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.62, "y":0.04}
        on_state: root.buttonpress(self,self.state)
        
    Button:
        id:calcretry
        text: "RETRY"
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.45, "y":0.7}
        on_release:
            root.showbuttons()
    TitleScreenButton:
        id:titlescreenbutton6
        text: "Gen new"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.33333, "y":0.66666}
        on_release: root.gensimple()
'''
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: I've added one, hopefully that helps find the problem

Comment: Can't follow what exactly you want it to happen?

Comment: The buttons should be visible immediately after clicking "Gen new". When you click the button a few red buttons should show up, but they are invisible until you press the "RETRY" button, which makes them appear. And if you click the "Gen new" button again, the buttons that were visible stay visible, but other buttons that appeared in new places are invisible until, again, you click the "RETRY" button.